# Default value for char in a constructor in C++

Tags: c++

Consider the following constructor of a class i C++. It gives me the error :

> default argument for parameter of type ‘char’ has type ‘const char [2]’

Some advices please. I would be happy if I could set the default constructor for `correctAnswer` at `""` (nothing).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Question{
    int id;
    std::string text;
    char correctAnswer;

public:

    Question(int id=0, const std::string& text="", char correctAnswer="a") : // here is the error
        id(id),text(text),correctAnswer(correctAnswer) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change it to

```
Question(int id=0, const std::string& text="",char correctAnswer='a')
```

`'a'` is a single char.

Double quotes always creates an array.

"Hello" is an array of size 6.

"a" is an array of size 2.

The extra 1 is for a null terminator (0 or '\0')

Answer (score 2):

```
Question(int id=0, const std::string& text="",
                            char correctAnswer='a')
//                                              ^^ Use single Quote for a char
        id(id),text(text),correctAnswer(correctAnswer) 
{

}
```